# mysql-connect error beginner

Tags: mysql

I finished a web page in my computer and it was saved in my pen drive.  Now I uploaded the files .html and .php to the server, and I exported the database of my pen drive and imported it on the web address using phpmyadmin. Seems like I'm having the following problem:

`Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/t1g01/doador.php on line 40`

The files in my pen drive are working fine. But not in the server. Can anyone help me please? When I explore the tables in the http://address.com/phpmyadmin/ there are normal, with data.

I read something in another topic about restarting the mysql by typing /etc/init.d/mysql restart or ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/ . If that's solve my problem, where am I supposed to type this ? I'm new at this server stuff.

Sorry for any mistake in English, and thanks in advance for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a page for common errors and troubleshooting help:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/common-errors.html

I also contributed a wiki page about connection troubleshooting:
http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Error2003-CantConnectToMySQLServer

You should also check whether your MySQL instance is using /tmp/mysql.sock or some other location for the mysql.sock file.  It's not uncommon for PHP and MySQL to have different ideas about where that file lives.

So check [`php.ini`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) and [`mysql.cnf`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) on your server.